# How to Make WebView Display SSL error Every Time Page is Reloaded?

Tags: android, ssl, webview

My webview application receive SSL error. It displays a warning message asking whether to load the website or not. On clicking yes button, it loads the website by ignoring the SSL error. But when I reload the same website it does not show me the warning message to handle the error and directly loads the website.

So, my question is **How to make the webview show me the warning message to handle SSL error everytime i reload the website?**

My code to handle ssl error is``

```
                    if(error.getPrimaryError()==SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED)
                    {

                        final Dialog sslalertdialog = new Dialog(browser.this);
                        sslalertdialog.setContentView(R.layout.sslerroralert);
                        sslalertdialog.show();
                        TextView sslalertmessage, sslalerttitle;
                        Button yes,no;
                        sslalertmessage= (TextView) sslalertdialog.findViewById(R.id.sslerrormessage);
                        sslalerttitle= (TextView) sslalertdialog.findViewById(R.id.sslerrorTitle);
                        String  message="The Website Security Certificate is Not Trusted." +
                                "One possible cause of this error is that a self-signed certificate is installed on the Website's server. " +
                                "Self-signed certificates aren't trusted by browsers because they are generated by Website's server, not by an accredited Certificate Authority (CA)." +
                                "Another cause of the error is that Someone is trying to intercept your communication." +
                                "You Should not Proceed,if you have never seen this error message for this Website before." +
                                "And if you want to proceed ,plz donot provide any sensitive Infomation to the site (like Credit Card Details " +
                                "Do you want to proceed anyways ?";
                        sslalerttitle.setText("The Website Cannot be Trusted!");
                        sslalertmessage.setText(message);
                        no=(Button) sslalertdialog.findViewById(R.id.NOBUTTON);
                        yes=(Button) sslalertdialog.findViewById(R.id.YES_BUTTON);
                        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                sslalertdialog.dismiss();
                                handler.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                sslalertdialog.dismiss();
                                handler.proceed();

                                padlock.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_warning_red_400_24dp));

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Any news on that one ? I ran into the same issue and need to show a dialog each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use clearSslPreferences() function of WebView like:

```
webView.clearSslPreferences()
```

It'll clear your decision for this object of WebView and you could get warning message again.